# Android save image in external storage

Tags: android

I am working on Android for saving multiple image in sd card but its getting save in gallery also and specific folder also...
any one can help on this
thanks..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        // 2
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        CharSequence time2 = android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                "yymmddhhmmss", new java.util.Date());
        String date1 = time2.toString();

        //ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         try {

                thumbnail .compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath()  + "/mypics/img" + date1 + ".png"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    } else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please take snap again",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: gallery takes all images from the device.. it is not a folder.. if u save any image in any folder, it will always shown in gallery

Comment: but in gallery itself its creating two folder one is 100MEDIA and one which i gave in code.

Answer (score 2):

try like this::

Use this function to save your bitmap in SD card

```
private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and add this permision in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to save in gallery just add this one:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: How can i call this function from intent

Comment: call in onActivityResult() after u r getting bitmapimage:: SaveIamge(thumbnail); and remove remaining code after that bitmap image

Comment: can someone help me how to save image from assets folder to gallery and image should be in new folder

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want images inside the `/mypics/img/` folder to be shown in the gallery. All you need to do is:

> Include an empty file named `.nomedia` in your `/mypcis/img/`
>   directory (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent
>   Android's media scanner from reading your media files and including
>   them in apps like Gallery or Music.

Note: For some devices, this only works for new folders (not those which are already scanned) So my recommendation would be to create a new folder with the `.nomedia` file and store your images to that. Now they will not appear in the gallery. Only in the external SD card folder.